# web2py, How to do SELECT ... FOR UPDATE?

Tags: web2py

I am learning web2py framework and Database Abstraction Level.
I need to do SELECT ... FOR UPDATE statement. Is there way to it in web2py?
I have not found answer in the [manual](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06)

Comment: You HAVE found an answer in the manual? Or do you mean that you have NOT found an answer in the manual? Cause if you found an answer then I don't know why you're asking the question.

Comment: @JesseJ sorry, I have NOT fount an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db(query).select(..., for_update=True)
```

Note, if you are using SQLite, this is simulated by wrapping the select and update in a transaction (which locks the entire database, not just the selected records).

Comment: Just do the update as usual. If the select and update are happening during an HTTP request to the framework, you don't have to explicitly commit the transaction, as that is done automatically at the end of the request.